# Conditional set variable in microsoft makefile

Tags: visual-studio, nmake

We have a nmake makefile (Microsoft, not Gnu) which uses vcvarsall.bat. With Dev15 changing vcvarsall.bat path, we need to conditionally set it.

I have added

```
if $(VISUALSTUDIOVERSION) == 15.0
        set VVA="$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"
    else
        set VVA="$(VSINSTALLDIR)\vc\vcvarsall.bat"
    endif
```

And this keeps giving an error:

```
if 15.0 == 15.0
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'if' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

I am new to nmake and possibly just thinking in lines of batch code. Is anyone able to stop what is wrong in my if-else construct?

Comment: So, how is that related to C or C++? (rhetorical question)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't. Because I was reading through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx assumed so.

Comment: Try `if "$(VISUALSTUDIOVERSION)" == "15.0"`

Comment: @user3286661 Thanks. I already tried that and the error said
if "15.0" == "15.0"..and the rest of the error statement.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem . the solution to this problem is that !IF and ENDIF statements should indented properly .so that compiler recognizes the End of IF directive. Indentation solved the problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

OP appears to be using 'if' when '!IF' was intended.